# Uncurry a curried function of n parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

If f :: a -> b -> c is curried then uncurry(f) can be defined as:

uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)

I'm trying to implement the above function in javascript. Is my below implementation correct and generic enough or are there are any better solution?

```
const uncurry = f => {
  if (typeof f != "function" || f.length == 0)
    return f;

  return function()
  {     
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
      f = f(arguments[i]);
    }

    return f;
  };
}


const curry = f => a => b => f(a, b);
const curriedSum = curry((num1, num2) => num1 + num2);
console.log(curriedSum(2)(3)); //5

console.log(uncurry(curriedSum)(2, 3)); //5
```

Comment: This is your fourth or fifth question in the last few days along these lines. I guess I'm curious, why are you trying to do all this *manually* instead of using Ramda? Not to mention that *all* of them could have been easily answered by glancing over the Ramda source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `uncurry` has three issues:

1. if not all expected arguments are passed it returns a curried function (which isn't the behavior of a normal, uncurried function)
2. it can't deal with unnecessary arguments
3. the implementation isn't very functional since you don't reuse anything

Here is a more functional approach:

```js
const id = x => x;
const uncurry = f => (x, y) => f(x)(y);

const uncurryn = n => f => (...xs) => {
  const next = acc => xs => xs.reduce(uncurry(id), acc);
  if (n > xs.length) throw new RangeError("too few arguments");
  return next(f) (xs.slice(0, n));
}

const sum = x => y => z => x + y + z;

try {uncurryn(3)(sum)(1, 2)} catch(e) {console.log(e.message)}
console.log(uncurryn(3)(sum)(1, 2, 3));
console.log(uncurryn(3)(sum)(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

`uncurryn` ignores unnecessary arguments like any other function in Javascript. It reuses `uncurry`, `reduce` and `id`.

If too few arguments are passed it throws an error, since it isn't clear in each case, which value should be returned (`NaN`, `undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad, but you assume that `f` is function until you loop through all arguments.

Also if you are using es6 consider using rest operator instead of `arguments`. And `for ... of` is nicer syntax in es6 to loop through values of array.

```js
const uncurry = f => {
  if (typeof f !== "function" || f.length == 0)
    return f;

  return (...args) => {     
    for (let arg of args) {
      if (typeof f !== "function") {
        return f;
      }
      
      f = f(arg);
    }

    return f;
  };
}




const curry = f => a => b => f(a, b);
const curriedSum = curry((num1, num2) => num1 + num2);
console.log(curriedSum(2)(3)); //5

console.log(uncurry(curriedSum)(2, 3)); //5
```